# How to persist Data Table selected items after data is updated/refreshed (Quasar-Framework)

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue.js, vuex

I'm using [Quasar Framework](http://quasar-framework.org/guide/) with VueJS. I have a [Data Table component](http://quasar-framework.org/components/data-table.html) that allows single item selection. The Data Table data is automatically updated every 5 seconds through websockets events. If I have an item selected, every time the Data Table data is updated, that item gets deselected, and I would like to persist the item selection after the data is updated.

Is there a way to accomplish this? I was thinking in two different approachs, but I have no idea how to do it, at least not from the [documentation](http://quasar-framework.org/guide/):

- access directly the Data Table selected item
- handle an event fired when an item is selected

In both cases the main idea would be to save the selection in a store, an restore the selection when the Data Table items update is done.

```
<template>
    <q-layout>
        <!-- Main block start-->
        <div class="scroll" style="width: 100%">
            <div class="layout-padding">
                <div class="row" style="margin-top: 30px;">
                    <q-data-table :data="dataTableData" :config="config" :columns="columns" @refresh="refresh">

                    </q-data-table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Man block end-->
    </q-layout>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    sockets:{
        connect: function(){
            console.log('socket connected')
        },
        info: function(data){
            console.log('sockets: info',data)
            //This is where I should get the current selected item if exists
            this.dataTableData = data;
            //This is where I should restore the selected item
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getInfo: function(val){
            this.$socket.emit('getInfo', val);
        },
        refresh (done) {
            this.$socket.emit('getInfo');
            done();
        }
    },
    created: function(){
        this.getInfo()
    },
    data: function () {
        return {
            dataTableData: [],
            config: {
                title: 'My Data Table',
                refresh: true,
                columnPicker: false,
                leftStickyColumns: 0,
                rightStickyColumns: 0,
                rowHeight: '50px',
                responsive: true,
                selection: 'single',
                messages: {
                    noData: '<i>warning</i> No data available to show.'
                }
            },
            columns: [
                { label: 'Name', field: 'name', width: '200px', sort: true },
                { label: 'Size', field: 'size', width: '50px', sort: true },
                { label: 'Status', field: 'status', width: '50px', sort: true },
                { label: 'Progress', field: 'progress', width: '150px', sort: false },
                { label: 'Speed', field: 'speed', width: '50px', sort: false },
                { label: 'ETA', field: 'eta', width: '50px', sort: false }
            ],
            pagination: false,
            rowHeight: 50,
            bodyHeightProp: 'auto',
            bodyHeight: 'auto'
        }
    },
    watch: {
    }
}
</script>
```

***UPDATE***
As far as I can see, [they're already working in this enenhancement](https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/milestone/12) for the Quasar-Framework v0.14 =)

Comment: I'd set up a watcher to intercept the 'update' method. That's where I would store the selected item as just a temp variable and then I'd just save it back, so the data in the table never actually had an unelected option. post your code for this component

Comment: @tam5 I can try that. Still, I have the problem of how to access the selected item in the Data Table, don't know how to do that.

Comment: Post your code, then we/I can help

Comment: @tam5 question updated with code, hope it helps

Comment: So how do you mark an item as selected? It looks like you have exactly what you need, you put a comment for where you would check the currently selected item, so I'm not sure what question remains, perhaps you can clarify

Comment: @tam5 items selection and deselection is done through the UI. My problem is that I don't know how to access de selected item from the Javascript code, how to know which item is currently selected at the moment. I've updated the question, maybe I wasn't clear about using Quasar Framework.